# Python-Getting contents between current and next occurrence of pattern in a string

Tags: python, regex, string

I want to implement the following in python

(1)Search pattern in a string

(2)Get content till next occurence of the same pattern in the same string

Till end of the string do (1) and (2)

Searched all available answers but of no use.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds like you want `re.split('pattern', text)`. It does exactly what you're asking for, except perhaps at the start and end of the string (it will give you the text before the first appearance of the pattern, and after the last).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by [Blckknght](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1405065/blckknght) in the comment, you can achieve this with `re.split`. `re.split` retains all empty strings between a) the beginning of the string and the first match, b) the last match and the end of the string and c) between different matches:

```
>>> re.split('abc', 'abcabcabcabc')
['', '', '', '', '']
>>> re.split('bca', 'abcabcabcabc')
['a', '', '', 'bc']
>>> re.split('c', 'abcabcabcabc')
['ab', 'ab', 'ab', 'ab', '']
>>> re.split('a', 'abcabcabcabc')
['', 'bc', 'bc', 'bc', 'bc']
```

If you want to retain only c) the strings between 2 matches of the pattern, just slice the resulting array with `[1:-1]`.

Do note that there are two caveat with this method:

1. `re.split` doesn't split on empty string match.

   ```
   >>> re.split('', 'abcabc')
   ['abcabc']
   ```
2. Content in capturing groups will be included in the resulting array.

   ```
   >>> re.split(r'(.)(?!\1)', 'aaaaaakkkkkkbbbbbsssss')
   ['aaaaa', 'a', 'kkkkk', 'k', 'bbbb', 'b', 'ssss', 's', '']
   ```

You have to write your own function with `finditer` if you need to handle those use cases.

This is the variant where only case c) is matched.

```
def findbetween(pattern, input):
    out = []
    start = 0
    for m in re.finditer(pattern, input):
        out.append(input[start:m.start()])
        start = m.end()
    return out
```

Sample run:

```
>>> findbetween('abc', 'abcabcabcabc')
['', '', '']
>>> findbetween(r'', 'abcdef')
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
>>> findbetween(r'ab', 'abcabcabc')
['c', 'c']
>>> findbetween(r'b', 'abcabcabc')
['ca', 'ca']
>>> findbetween(r'(?<=(.))(?!\1)', 'aaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbkkkkkkk')
['bbbbbbbbbbbb', 'kkkkkkk']
```

(In the last example, `(?<=(.))(?!\1)` matches the empty string at the end of the string, so `'kkkkkkk'` is included in the list of results)

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this

```
re.findall(r"pattern.*?(?=pattern|$)",test_Str)
```

Here we search `pattern` and with `lookahead` make sure it captures till next `pattern` or `end of string`.